# How to go on next page using push button in qt c++ with out use of signal and slots?

Tags: qt, qt5

I created table widget with check box and push button.

Now ,how to go on next page with all checked data, after click on push button.

Comment: Without some [MCVE] your question is unclear. You need to define a Qt slot doing that appropriate operation. Read more about [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: But i don't want to use signal and slots @BasileStarynkevitch

I just want to switch between two window with data using push button.


If i click on push button then it can take all checked data and go to the next window.

Comment: Then you should not use Qt. Since [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) is the basic mechanism in Qt for that (and to tailor the behavior of some Qt widgets, such as buttons).

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted and is not an [MCVE]. It should have a `main` function to become one

Comment: Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53993545/edit) your question** to improve it a lot: format properly your code, extend it to make it some [MCVE] (with a `main`), and explain *in details* (with several paragraphs) why you don't want to use [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch now please check

Comment: You still don't explain why you want to avoid [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). IMHO this is non-sense when using Qt. And there is still no `main` in your question

Comment: your `on_pushButton_clicked` seems to be useless

Comment: Yes, its didnt get any output..how can i add push button now?? @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: My answer explains that. Of course you *do* need to use [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and perhaps define `on_pushButton_clicked` as some slot somewhere.

Comment: Okay thanks @BasileStarynkevitch for advice, but can you please help me to write signal and slots here in this code ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again, my answer give some hints. There are many tutorials and examples. And no, I don't have time to write your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch hello I make some changes and add signal and slots in my code now can you please tell me how to go on next page with all checked data? Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry. **I won't write your code.** Please take several days or weeks to **study the documentation of Qt**. You really need to do this. And the documentation of Qt is *very well written*, you just need to read it. My answer should be enough. If you can't write your code, consider paying someone to do that. I am not a Qt consultant.

Comment: What you should apologize about is not the length of your code (it is acceptable) but the fact that you refuse to carefully read the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/index.html). We cannot (and should not) do that effort for you.

Comment: Hey @BasileStarynkevitch  I am beginner in QT so don't know how to go on next page with all data. 
If i know all the documentation of QT then no need to post this questions. My all doubts are cleared but having this small doubt that's why i say you.
BTW **Thanks** for giving suggestions.

Comment: This just means that you need *more time* to read *more carefully* the Qt documentation (yes, learning Qt takes several weeks). Yes, it is dense but well written. For your next question, provide a *simpler example* which is some [MCVE] (so includes all the header files, all your classes, and the `main` function) and give the compilation commands

Comment: BTW, your question mentions "going to the next page" but you never define what a "page" means to you (and what "going to the next page" means). That is probably your main problem (and could require days of thinking and of work). You really should throw your code and start again, after having spent several weeks reading Qt documentation

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch going to next page means here in  code i am switching on next page that is secdialog here..

Comment: Yes, but that notion of next page is a concept of your application. `QTableView` don't know about pages. So you need to define that concept (on paper), and to implement that. Again, I won't write your code, and you should spend a whole week at least reading Qt documentation (and throw your current code to the thrash bin)

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>the initial question was:</sup>

> How to go on next page using push button in qt c++ without use of [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)?

**This is practically impossible**, and certainly inadvisable, since Qt signals and slots is the *basic foundational mechanism* of Qt, used everywhere inside it.

Be sure to take more time to understand [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and study several Qt tutorials and [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamples.html). Consider also studying the source code of Qt5 itself (since it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)). And you can also find many Qt [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) applications (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.org/), inside a [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), etc...) which should be inspirational (if you don't have time, you could pay some Qt consulting corporation to do your work).

My recommendation is to create some Qt [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html) (perhaps subclassing that) and [`connect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) its [`clicked` signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) to your appropriate slot somewhere. The [calculator example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-calculator-example.html) should be inspirational. You probably should subclass `QTableWidget` to add a new slot, and use that for your `m_pTableWidget` or at least *declare* your `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked` as a public slot (and of course `connect` it appropriately).

If you don't want to use Qt signals and slots, you should give up using Qt and choose [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) other [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit). They all have some notification machinery (at least based on [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))), and IMHO the design of Qt signals and slots is quite good (and sometimes better than what other toolkits provide).

---

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

It seems that you don't understand the design principles of Qt (i.e. the fact that  [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are *central* to Qt, so you should use them *extensively*). So I recommend taking a few days to study carefully the [documentation of Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/) (it is well written, but extensive; start with [*Getting Started Programming with Qt Widgets*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html)) and the source code of existing examples (including Qt itself); **throw your current code to the trash bin; then rewrite it with an [iterative and incremental development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) approach** : code a few dozen lines at once, compile them (with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)), improve them to get no warnings, test your incomplete program - [using the GDB debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) -, make sure it works as you want it to, and add one more small feature (perhaps just a single new widget) and repeat. Of course, use a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (I recommend [git](https://git-scm.com/)) and commit your code frequently (at least, at every loop of your iterative and incremental development approach).

NB. **you have changed your question *entirely*** (at first, you refused to use [Qt signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html); now you accept to use them). Of course, you need to **read carefully the documentation** of every used widget (including the superclasses), notably of [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) and of [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html). And you need to define what a "page" is (and what going to the next page means), since [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) don't know about them.

### take time (several days or a few weeks) to read the [documentation of Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/reference-overview.html).